# SmartWatch Battery stats?

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch

How do I read the battery status of the SmartWatch? (Not of the host, but of the watch itself!) That's needed, since an app can have the screen always on, and drain the battery, so I want to display at least some kind of warning.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's possible.  it would be a nice addition to the api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this feature is not available.

Comment: Hi Jerker, thanks for the reply. The host does know this information, so it's being propagated. Maybe it's just not documented, but it exists?

Comment: The host does actually not know - the battery status in the status bar on the watch is rendered by the firmware in the SmartWatch.

Comment: Ok, now it's clear. But please do have in mind that reading the battery status is needed, as mentioned, especially when the screen is set to be on!